# Error using NB model in textmodel() of quanteda package

Tags: r, text-mining, cross-validation, quanteda

I am trying to fit a model to dfm I created using quanteda. I am getting the following error. Any ideas??

```
tModel <- textmodel(udfm1,model = "NB", smooth=1)

Error in textmodel(udfm1, model = "NB", smooth = 1) : 
model NB not implemented.
```

p.s. I am creating a model to predict the next word for mobile application. I only know Naive Bayes and am not familiar with the other models in this package. So feel free to recommend.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for this: while the `?textmodel` indicates that `"NB"` is an available model, in fact as of quanteda v0.9.1-7 it's not yet implemented.  I have code that implements multinomial and Bernoulli Naive Bayes as a textmodel type but we moved it to a development branch pending more testing.  (But coming soon.)

For predicting the next word, that sounds like a question for the [text-mining tag of Cross-Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-mining).  Nothing directly in quanteda yet for this, but you should be able to use the dfm directly with most classifiers and regression models.

Comment: thanks. I have added the other two tags to this post. So hopefully, someone can recommend which of the following model in quanteda would be suitable for text prediction (wordscores, ca, wordfish)